# Confusing use of noun following て form

Tags: sentence

Context from show: villain tries to trick opponent into thinking they were cornered, but it was actually the villain in the end who was cornered):

《 追い詰められたのは
俺のほうと見せかけて**奴のほうだった**のに
そう見せかけて本当に追い詰められていたのは
俺のほう … 》

I let him think he had the advantage
so I could turn the tables on him.
But it looks as though the one
who was backed into a corner...
was me... (show's translation)

The confusing part is the first half.
My more literal translation of everything before 奴のほう was:

"Feigning that the one who had been cornered was me (my side)..."
Makes sense, but then it goes to 奴のほうだった, "It was him (his side)".
Literally from first glance it comes together as:
"Feigning that the one who had been cornered was me (my side)...it was him (his side)" (leaving out the のに)

The て form immediately to 奴のほう does not make sense to me.
My only guess is that 奴のほう may be a shortening of 奴のほうから, "It was from his side that...", but I'm not confident in that. I don't know how to parse this properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'AとみせかけてB' means 'feigning A, but it is actually B' (cf. 'AではなくB' is 'not A but B')

Thus

> 追い詰められたのは 俺のほうと見せかけて奴のほうだった,

means something like (though I guess the use 'feign' below may not be completely correct):

> The one/side who was cornered was 'feigned as' my side, but it (=the cornered side) was actually their side.

Then the rest of the sentence flips the feigning and the actual situation again, and says the above was the feigning and it is actually 'my' side that was cornered.